# Using baking soda paste (alkaline) to "neutralize" honeybee venom (acidic). Is this scientifically sound?

Tags: acid-base, everyday-chemistry, proteins

I recall reading (courtesy: my 9th grade Chemistry text-book, chapter *Acids, Bases and Salts*), something along the lines of:

> Bee venom is acidic. This is why the area of skin (stung by a bee) is treated (first-aid) by the topical application of a sodium bicarbonate paste. This method works by neutralization of the acidic venom.

The problems with this theory? I see three:

**Firstly,**

A honeybee's stinger can grow to be [as long as 3mm.](https://www.quora.com/How-big-is-a-honey-bees-stinger) If bee venom were acidic, then how would the baking-soda paste neutralize it (entirely) by simply applying it on the surface?

**Secondly,**

Wikipedia provides the [composition of honeybee venom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apitoxin);

> Melittin
>
> Apamin
>
> Adolapin
>
> Phospholipase A2
>
> Hyaluronidase
>
> Histamine
>
> Dopamine and Noradrenaline
>
> Tertiapin

As far as I know...none of these are actual *acids*, instead, they're pretty much all *proteins*. Which appears to seriously contradict the popular "Bee venom is acidic" notion.

**Thirdly,**

Some sources (online) suggest that [application of *vinegar* (which is acidic) also relieves the pain](http://www.healthline.com/health/outdoor-health/home-remedies-for-bee-stings#home-remedies2). Additionally, even meat tenderizers (proteases), toothpaste and wet aspirin tablets seem to do the trick.

---

So I'll break up my question into two bits (to hopefully, make it easier to answer):

1) Is honeybee venom *acidic*? If so, what substance present in it is responsible for the "acidic" nature of the venom?

2) Why does applying baking-soda (paste) relieve the pain? Does it somehow denature/"neutralize" the venom?

Answer (score 1):

1. Honeybee venom **is** acidic. It contains formic acid, also known as $\ce{HCOOH}$. However,
2. Rubbing baking soda probably isn't really reducing the pain because

   - The formic acid isn't causing the pain
   - The venom is injected under tissue
   - The ratio of venom to baking soda is way out of proportion

For more information, visit [this website](https://www.insectstings.co.uk/bee-sting-acid-or-alkali/).

Comment: @Javascripter One interesting point in your linked webpage "applying hot water to coagulate the venom".. Ha... Ha..

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post an answer! A tip on formatting though: For emphasis, you can *italicize* words or put them in **bold**; typing it out in UPPERCASE however, as you did with "IS", can sometimes yield other (more dubious) meanings ;)

Comment: @Mocking Yeah...which is pretty much why I'm not (completely) buying what that site says :D

Comment: As para shown it doesn't contain HCOOH, it's only "formic" not "beeic" acid.